# Flutter app stuck on "running gradle task 'assembledebug'"

Tags: flutter

I have been looking for someone with a similar issue all over and have not managed to find someone so here I go making a question instead.

When I try to run my flutter app in VS Code with android emulator (I have previously have it working) it gets stuck on "Running gradle task 'assembleDebug'". It can stay here forever. The weird thing is if I open the android emulator and manually open the app, everything is fine. The debug session works and is responsive to edits, as well as hot reload/restart working as expected.

I have tried running the app with flutter run -v to get more detailed view and it seemed to always stop and get the error

"Error type 3
Error: Activity class {[appId]/MainActivity} does not exist."

I have tried:

1. Cleaning the project
2. Clearing the cache
3. Flutter clean
4. adb uninstall
5. ./gradlew clean & ./gradlew build

I hope someone has another idea for how to fix this as it seemingly came out of nowhere and has been bugging me and incredible amount lately.

Comment: Personally, I've never encountered the problem (I use VSCode for my Flutter/Android projects, too).  But you seem to be doing all the right things, in the right order: 1) Terminate everything; restart VSCode, restart your avd, 2) Clean the project, 3) ADB uninstall the app, 4) Clear the Gradle caches. Specifically: physically delete  `android\.gradle\*` (under the project folder) and `$USER\.gradle\caches\*` (global), try rebuilding, and redeploying to your avd (or actual handset).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your MainActivity File in android folder is persistent.
The Error Code tells that this file is not existent. The weird thing is that without that file you literally were not be able to run the app.

[image]

If it's there check out your Android Manifest in main android/app/main folder and look if android:name=".MainActivity" is set in activity tag

[image]

Then check your app level and top level build.gradle if it looks like this:

enter image description here

[image]

[image]